# Using generator as an iterator in an ES2015 class

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, es6-class

[Please find the complete code example in action here.](http://babeljs.io/repl/#?babili=false&evaluate=true&lineWrap=false&presets=es2015%2Creact%2Cstage-2&targets=&browsers=&builtIns=false&debug=false&code_lz=MYGwhgzhAEDKAy8CWEAuA5A9gEwKbQG8AoaU6YTAOzQCcBXYVTGgCiVVwFsBKQksgagAWKAHTsu0ALzQJnANz9SAXyXQA2rACenAEaYQoprFQ0klAOYAVMBYC6LXsQECauVHRqVoAAwAkBMJicso-igKqqkSgkDCw5hYgWsiUANa42MhofAIU1KYMTKxOaoIiEKIguJbC0tAADOFkqgJg2NgAYkg0aGwcPDkupHnZlLgA7lh4dWPjcIgoGDi4fVzcTUOzU7iiYwAeqHVBFUK4bRsux6KnbTMT2xdlYlU1QgDUbxctZABUmjr6QwSGhgIoOEpDYZUCAGHYgTAWFgAcgAkhwQUVyGAQFVsEj1qUyFVDv0AA5HcrXM7YR5kcYiKrQFhkiGQgRaJC4EDYaBk8T9WlDMlHLik3a4A6C6DfFRqCzueDVCzCRyDIZuDxeXmUl7KoRfNT_PQGIyYExmSw2eyq5yQgBmzCZIxJougmDt2pQrLZpA1nm8_kCouU0AAtAA-XxSmXSohRZ3QECLO5zeKWJIpdKZRaORRJtCiNqdbq9ADMBPzqEL7S6PVQLAATBXFtXi3WWABGAkjWGVBEsSvrIA)

I'm trying to use generator as iterator and combine it with `for..of` loop in `toString` but somehow it's not working.

Here is how my (generator) iterator looks like -

```
*[Symbol.iterator]() {
    let temp = this.head;
    while (temp) {
        yield temp.item;
        temp = temp.next;
    }
}
```

And then I'm trying to use it in the `toString` method as shown below -

```
[Symbol.toStringTag]() {
    for (const temp of this) {
        return `${temp} -> `;
    }
}
```

I would imagine that using `for..of` loop with `this` reference should call the iterator but it doesn't. This can be observed by the absence of `Iterator called` statements in the console log and the object is printed using default `toString` instead.

Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: `Symbol.toStringTag` is not the same as `toString`. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I''m trying to provide a `toString` implementation. I thought these were the same thing as the [Mozilla doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol/toStringTag)  states that it is called internally by `Object.prototype.toString()` method. Even if I change it to plain `toString` I get the same behaviour. I'm looking to get `1 -> 2 -> 3` like representation of the list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @bergi and @loganfsmyth, whose answers pointed out the mistakes in my original code and pushed me in right direction, here the solution that works and makes use of generator as iterator -

```
class SLListNode {
    constructor(item) {
        this.item = item;
    }
    toString() {
        return `${this.item}`;
    }
}
class SinglyLinkedList {
    constructor() {
        this.length = 0;
    }
    addFirst(item) {
        const newNode = new SLListNode(item);
        newNode.next = this.head;
        this.head = newNode;
        this.length++;
    }
    *[Symbol.iterator]() {
        let temp = this.head;
        while (temp) {
            yield temp.item;
            temp = temp.next;
        }
    }
    getLength() {
        return this.length;
    }
    toString() {
        let str = "";
        for (const temp of this) {
            str = `${str} -> ${temp}`;
        }
        return str;
    }
}
const list = new SinglyLinkedList();
list.addFirst(3);
list.addFirst(2);
list.addFirst(1);
console.log(list.toString());
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a few big issues

1. `Symbol.toStringTag` is supposed to be a property that resolves to a string, not a function. This means

   ```
   [Symbol.toStringTag]() {
   ```

   should be

   ```
   get [Symbol.toStringTag]() {
   ```

   so that the property is a getter that will return a string on access.
2. `console.log(list)` does not call `.toString()`, so you need `console.log(list.toString())`.
3. You'll notice, `list.toString() === "[object 1 -> ]"`, which is *also* probably not what you want. `toStringTag` gets appended inside another string, kind of like

   ```
   `[object ${this[Symbol.toStringTag]}]`
   ```

   so if you actually want a nice string output, you probably just want

   ```
   toString() {
   ```

   as your method, skipping `toStringTag`.
4. Your loop doesn't make sense if you're trying to serialize the whole list, since you `return` the very first item in the list, and never bother to process the rest of the items.

So in the end, I would probably write what you're trying to do as

```
toString() {
  let result = "";
  for (let item = this.head; item; item = item.next) {
    if (result) result += ' -> ';
    result += item.item;
  }
  return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> I would imagine that using `for..of` loop with this reference should call the iterator but it doesn't.

It does. You just were never calling the method in your example.

> the object is printed to console using default `toString` instead

It doesn't, it's printed using the console's own object representation (on the babeljs.io repl, that appears to be a mix of the `.constructor.name` and `JSON.stringify`).

> … `toString` method as shown below - `[Symbol.toStringTag]() { …`

No. [`Symbol.toStringTag`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol/toStringTag) is used as a part of the standard `toString` representation when inherited by `Object.prototype`. And it's not a method, but a plain value (you could use a getter, but you shouldn't).

If you want to implement a custom `toString` method, actually implement *that*.

Here's an updated example that does what you want:

```
class SLListNode {
    constructor(item, next) {
        this.item = item;
        this.next = next;
    }
    toString() {
        return `${this.item} -> ${this.next}`;
    }
}

class SinglyLinkedList {
    constructor() {
        this.length = 0;
        this.head = null;
    }
    addFirst(item) {
        this.head = new SLListNode(item, this.head);
        this.length++;
    }
    *[Symbol.iterator]() {
        console.log('Iterator called');
        let temp = this.head;
        while (temp) {
            yield temp.item;
            temp = temp.next;
        }
    }
    getLength() {
        return this.length;
    }
    toString() {
        return `{ ${this.head.toString()} }`;
    }
}
SinglyLinkedList.prototype[Symbol.toStringTag] = "LinkedList";

const list = new SinglyLinkedList();
list.addFirst(3);
list.addFirst(2);
list.addFirst(1);
console.log(String(list)); // "{ 1 -> 2 -> 3 -> null }"
console.log(Object.prototype.toString.call(list)); // "[object LinkedList]"
```

Comment: I just realized that while the solution above definitely works and one way of doing it, it doesn't actually use the iterator. You can simply delete the `*[Symbol.iterator]()` implementation and it still works. Actually my original toString was lame as mentioned by @loganfsmyth. I'll post the working version below. Thanks for your answer as I learnt quite a bit about `toString` and `Symbol.toStringTag` and it pushed me in right direction.

Comment: @OmkarPatil To use the iterator, you can do something like ``return `{ ${Array.from(this).join(" -> ")} -> null}` ``